# Open source component-based game engines?

Tags: c#, c++, component-based

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there existing FOSS component-based frameworks?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4898/are-there-existing-foss-component-based-frameworks)

What open source game engines with component-based design of game objects do you know? And which best of them? I mean best not in Graphics or Physics, but best in context of Behaviour, Messaging, etc.

This question is the result of inspiration by another [question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/22630/the-game-object-and-component-based-design)

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

CraftyJS meets your criteria - component based and open source. It is a Javascript based 2D game/graphics engine.

http://craftyjs.com